# Multiply defined symbols - Linker error

Tags: c++, linker

I face an issue when I build and link my code with GHS multi compiler.
This is roughly the idea:

base.h -->

```
#ifndef base_h
#define base_h
class Base
{
    void basefncn1(); // defined in src file
    void basefncn2(); // defined in src file
    void basefncn3(); // defined in src file
}
#endif
```

interface.h -->

```
#ifndef interface_h
#define interface_h

#include "base.h"
class Interface : public Base
{
    void basefncn1();
}

#endif
```

derivedclass.h -->

```
#ifndef derived_h
#define derived_h

#include "base.h"
#include "interface.h"
class Derived : public Interface
{
    void basefncn1();
}

#endif
```

The linker error I get is:

```
basefncn2() and basefncn3() is multiply defined -> Defined both in base.o and derived.o.
```

The header files are guarded.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Edit: I tried changing the interface.h file. The function is now defined in interface.cpp.
So basically, interface.h and derived.h does not have functions defined in it.

Comment: Dunno if it's related, but you should be doing e.g. #include "base.h" rather than #include <base.h>

Comment: Most likely, You define a function in a header file and then include that header file in multiple trnalsation units. This breaks the one definition rule. Is this your actual code?

Comment: sorry, i was doing that...just happened to put it wrong here..let me try correcting it in the question...thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: @AlokSave: No, this is not my actual code. But, why does the multiple defined symbol error come for basefncn2() and basefncn3()?

Comment: You will have to post the actual code minus the irrelevant details to get a answer rather than guesses.

Comment: where are those functions defined?